# Uploading a text file a 3 form fields to an API using msxml2.serverXMLhttp.6.0

Tags: text, asp-classic, upload, serverxmlhttp

I need to post 3 form-data fields and text file to an api endpoint.  I am using msxml2.serverXMLhttp.6.0 and I have several API calls working with it just fine.  But theres one where a text file need to be uploaded.

I am creating the multipart payload but I am unsure how to get the file to upload. The API doc is here http://developer.act-on.com/documentation/list-api/endpoint-update-merge-list/

I believe it is not API specific but rather a simple matter of getting a text file and a few form fields transferred using msxml2.serverXMLhttp.6.0  and multipart/form-data

I know I am missing something and it may be obvious... Just not to me

```vbs
strRequestStart = "--" & strBoundary & vbCrlf & _
    "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""listname""" & vbCrlf & vbCrlf & _
    "rob666" & vbCrlf & vbCrlf & _
    "--" & strBoundary & vbCrlf & _
    "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""foldername""" & vbCrlf & vbCrlf & _
    "" & vbCrlf & vbCrlf & _
    "--" & strBoundary & vbCrlf & _
    "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""headings""" & vbCrlf & vbCrlf & _
    "N" & vbCrlf & vbCrlf & _
    "--" & strBoundary & vbCrlf & _
    "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""fieldseparator""" & vbCrlf & vbCrlf & _
    "COMMA" & vbCrlf & vbCrlf & _
    "--" & strBoundary & vbCrlf & _
    "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""quotecharacter""" & vbCrlf & vbCrlf & _
    "DOUBLE_QUOTE" & vbCrlf & vbCrlf & _
    "--" & strBoundary & vbCrlf & _
    "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""uploadspecs""" & vbCrlf & vbCrlf & _
    Server.URLEncode(uploadspecs) & vbCrlf & vbCrlf & _
    "--" & strBoundary & vbCrlf & _
    "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""file""; filename=""" & strFilename & """" & vbCrlf & _
    "Content-Type: text/comma-separated-values" & vbCrlf & _
    "--" & strBoundary & "--" & vbCrlf

set HTTP=server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
HTTP.Open "POST", ("https://restapi.actonsoftware.com/api/1/list"), False
HTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type","multipart/form-data; boundary=--" & sBoundary
HTTP.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & access_token 
HTTP.send(strRequestStart)
```

The text file is in the same directory as the asp page and permissions are correct.
I have correctly configured the boundary segments and closed the boundary at the end

Is Content-Length needed?

Comment: as far as i understand that you have to upload the file not just post the filename. just like when you upload a file with your browser to the webserver.

Comment: @ulluoink is correct. You are not performing any steps to encode and include the file DATA in the HTTP REQUEST that you are sending. You would need to MIME encode the message and file header which would then have its actual data BASE64 encoded within that.